# Cadastro de usuário e senha

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com um problema de aceitação. Após ter configurado o `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData` e as classes correspondentes, o sistema criou corretamente as tabelas no banco para que eu pudesse implementar o código para cadastro de usuário, senha e confirmação de senha. Bom, a ideia é gravar no WebData e na minha tabela normalmente, mas quando roda e debugo funciona até chegar no método  `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.Email, model.Senha.ToString())`.

O debug informa que estão login e senha perfeitamente, mas o erro diz que não add senha nula. Alguém faz ideia do que está faltando?

Desde já agradeço. Abaixo a imagem que comprova o erro e os códigos de configuração.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Configuração do WebConfig:

```
<system.web>
    <!-- Outras configurações -->
    <membership defaultProvider="churrascadaProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="churrascadaProvider"
             type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
</system.web

<appSettings>
    <!-- Outras configurações -->
    <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Conta"/>
</appSettings>
```

---

Dentro do application start do Global.asax:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ChurrascadaContext", "Contas", "IdConta", "Email", true);
```

---

Código do Controller:

```
    // POST: Conta/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(ContaModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.Email, model.Senha.ToString());

                //Buscando o Id da Conta no banco e inserindo no objeto conta
                Conta conta = new Conta();
                conta.IdConta = contasDAO.BuscaPorEmail(conta.Email).IdConta;

                return RedirectToAction("Create", "Usuario", new {idConta = conta.IdConta });
            }
            catch(MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("usuario.invalido", e.Message);
                return View("Create", model);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Create", model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Para você precisar dar um ToString() em sua senha no controller, ela é que tipo de variável?

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei o problema. Acontece que o sistema estava buscando a senha da entidade "Contas", mas ela estava vazia, pois tinha configurado o Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData para armazenar a senha. Sendo assim, a solução era buscar do próprio Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData a senha para fazer a validação.

Comment: Ronnam dê aceite na sua resposta para que a pergunta não fique aberta